# How to identify iOS device(instead of imei)

Tags: ios, uikit

I want to uniquely identify devices of my app users. Since I can't have imei, what are other options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IMEI as a fallback of UDID, is it a good idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342094/imei-as-a-fallback-of-udid-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: What do you think about the Device Token?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601011/saving-the-devicetoken-for-later-use-in-apple-push-notification-services

Comment: Using the device token is not a good idea for multiple reasons.  1) The device token changes each time the user restores iOS to their device.  2) The device token is different for the same device depending on whether the app was build using a development profile vs. a distribution profile.  3) The device token is really intended for use with Apple Push Notifications.  Please see my answer below for a better recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create our own UDID's based on a hash of the device MAC address and the bundle identifier.  This ensures that we can uniquely identify our app on a specific device.

You could also create a hash based only on the MAC address if you need a unique ID across multiple apps.

I've actually written a blog post about how to do this and provided some sample code here:

https://radeeccles.com/blog/create-your-own-unique-device-identifier-udid

Answer (score 0):

You might have a try with OpenUDID.